# How does ifttt.com authenticate a supplied WordPress account

Tags: authentication, authorization

I'm curious to know how [ifttt.com](https://ifttt.com/wordpress) authenticate a supplied WordPress admin login credentials. And after authorization is granted, how does it publish post on our behalf? am curious to know what communication protocol it is using.

Comment: WordPress com service runs their own [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) (this is different from the one being developed for WordPress itself). Please note that dot com is mostly considered out of scope here. :)

Comment: Hi, am not talking about a dot com. Am using a self hosted site and it authenticated successfully.
Am confused because the my self hosted site doesn't have Jetpack nor connected to wordpress.com

Comment: Ah, sorry, I must have misread the question. :)

Comment: @Rarst Do you think they could be using WordPress XML-RPC ?

Comment: It might be... You could disable XML-RPC and try again to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IFTTT.com connects to your WordPress site via XML-RPC, as the [dudes at wpbeginner.com already found](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-automate-wordpress-and-social-media-with-ifttt/) out:

> Go to IFTTT and create your account. IFTTT works with all WordPress.org self-hosted blogs (version 3.x and above) and WordPress.com blogs as well. You MUST have XML-RPC enabled to work with IFTTT.